# Управление в Godot Engine 4

Tags: godot, gdscript

У меня есть 3D проект в Godot (шутер от первого лица), и для игрока естественно нужен скрипт управления и перемещения. Но из-за определённых строк в коде, которые необходимы для перемещения игрока, игра запускается, но не отвечает и зависает. Причём этот же код прекрасно работал на предыдущих версиях. Вот сам код:

```
    extends CharacterBody3D

const ROT = 0.01
const Gr = -20
const SPEED = 120
var vel = Vector3()

const J_SPEED = 10

var rot_x = 0
var rot_y = 0

func _ready():
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)



func _physics_process(delta):
    var dir = Vector3()

    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_cancel"):
        get_tree().quit()
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left"):
        dir.x = -1
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right"):
        dir.x = 1
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_down"):
        dir.z = 1
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
        dir.z = -1
    
    if dir:
        dir *= SPEED * delta
        dir = dir.rotated(Vector3(0,1,0), rotation.y)

    vel.x = dir.x
    vel.z = dir.z
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_select"):
        if is_on_floor():
            vel.y = J_SPEED
    
    vel.y += Gr * delta

    vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector3(0,1,0))

func _input(e):
    if e is InputEventMouseMotion:
        rot_y -= e.relative.x * ROT
        rot_x -= e.relative.y * ROT
        
        if rot_x < -1: rot_x = -1
        if rot_x > 1: rot_x = 1
        
        transform.basis = Basis(Vector3(0,1,0), rot_y)
        $cam.transform.basis = Basis(Vector3(1,0,0), rot_x)
```

Ошибка возникает при наличии строк:

vel.x = dir.x

vel.z = dir.z

vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector3(0,1,0))

Comment: move_and_slide не принимает никаких аргументов, а вы передали целых два, это ошибка. Ещё он ничего не возвращает

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужно выкинуть свою переменную `vel` и вместо неё использовать встроенную переменную `velocity`, которая появилась в Godot 4 и которую собственно и использует этот самый move_and_slide

Comment: Игра запускается, персонаж ходит. Но когда кнопка движения зажата и персонаж должен двигаться без остановки, он двигается один раз, то есть он ходит по одному разу. Приходится нажимать кнопку много раз. Как добавить беспрерывное движение?

Comment: Метод is_action_just_pressed специально проверяет, что кнопка НЕ зажата. Может, вам нужен метод is_action_pressed?

Comment: И вообще все эти банальные вещи описаны в [официальном туториале](https://docs.godotengine.org/ru/stable/getting_started/first_3d_game/index.html), возможно вам стоит его пройти

Comment: (хм, в русском переводе до сих пор устаревший код... придётся читать туториал на английском https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_3d_game/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

В место vel, надо вписать velocity, например:

```
    velocity.x = dir.x    
    velocity.z = dir.z
    velocity = move_and_slide(vel, Vector3(0,1,0))
```

А если хотите чтобы персонаж при нажатии на кнопку движения подвинулся лишь один раз, надо написать:
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up")
dir.z = -1
А если же вы хотите что бы при нажатии и задержке кнопки ваш персонаж двигался без призывно, то напишите:
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up")
dir.z = -1
В общем, надо писать не: is_action_just_pressed, а: is_action_pressed!